# HttpClient put issue in Angular

Tags: c#, angular, httpclient, put

I'm developing an Angular app with Web api.

I have created a service (sellerService) in which I can update some data in my database with `HttpClient put`.

Above works but it update all the data of my table, something like follows;

**Before I update my seller:**

[image: BEFORE]

**After I update my seller:**

[image: AFTER]

**My sellerService code:**

```
  updateSeller(user: string, nbsales: number, pVote: number, nVote: number, idUser: number): Observable<any> {
      return this.http.put('http://localhost:50867/api/seller_user/', {
        'username': user,
        'nbSales': nbsales,
        'positiveVote': pVote,
        'negativeVote': nVote,
        'idUser': idUser
      });
    }
```

**My update query (DAO (c#)):**

```
public static readonly string UPDATE = "update " + TABLE_NAME + " set "
            + COLUMN_USERNAME + " =@username"
            + ", " + COLUMN_NB_SALES + "=@nbSales"
            + ", " + COLUMN_POSITIVE_VOTE + "=@positiveVote"
            + ", " + COLUMN_NEGATIVE_VOTE + " =@negativeVote"
            + ", " + COLUMN_ID_USER + "=@idUser";

        //Update a seller_user
        public static bool Update(Seller_user todo)
        {
            bool state = false;
            using (SqlConnection connection = DataBase.GetConnection())
            {
                connection.Open();
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(UPDATE, connection);

                //command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idSeller", todo.idSeller);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", todo.username);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nbSales", todo.nbSales);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@positiveVote", todo.positiveVote);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@negativeVote", todo.negativeVote);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idUser", todo.idUser);

                state = command.ExecuteNonQuery() != 0;
            }
            return state;
        }
```

Thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed [where](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp) clause in SQL query. So it will update all records.

```
public static readonly string UPDATE = "update " + TABLE_NAME + " set "
            + COLUMN_USERNAME + " =@username"
            + ", " + COLUMN_NB_SALES + "=@nbSales"
            + ", " + COLUMN_POSITIVE_VOTE + "=@positiveVote"
            + ", " + COLUMN_NEGATIVE_VOTE + " =@negativeVote"
            + ", " + COLUMN_ID_USER + "=@idUser"
            + "WHERE "  + COLUMN_ID_USER + "=" + "= @idUser";
```

Comment: Thank that perform ;)